# Disadvantage of single page application with jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I Started a asp.net mvc project with few views, This project have a layout for all views, In layout exist application menus, Each menu is anchor tag with proper action url.

```
//spAnchorLoad class is nothing except for custom anchor selector
<a tabindex="-1" href="/Home/UsersManageView" class="spAnchorLoad">
```

So when user click a menu then page reloaded and going to relative view.

I decided to have a single page without reloading page for a view request `(Albeit i don't want use angularjs or other sp framework)` so i design a main page like layout and disable layout for all views. In this main page i handle anchor click event and then i get href and load view in content:

```
<div id="MainContainer" class="row">

</div>
```

...

```
$('a.spAnchorLoad').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    $('#MainContainer').fadeOut(function () {
        $('#MainContainer').load(href, function () {
            $('#MainContainer').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

This solution is nice and working perfectly. In later i will add some many view in project progress but i don't have any idea that this solution is work in all scenario, beacause may be exist a scenario that i don't think about that and i will meet it later and i could't handle it anyway. So in your exprience does this way is ok and i continue it or may exist disadvantages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my experience, it's totally doable, but it gets quite difficult to manage for larger sites. Also, it takes a lot of work to get it to work properly with SEO and the site meta data, and you also need to really stay on top of the URLs. And, you really need to make sure your memory management in Javascript is good, a leak can kill your site. So yes, it's doable, but it's more difficult and doesn't give enough of an advantage to do it for an entire site, in most cases.